# EGA remote download via snakemake fails due to EGA_CLIENT_ID specification

Tags: snakemake

The example code provided by the [Snakemake documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html) for remote downloading from the EGA archive fails for me. I have defined all required environment variables, but an error comes up stating

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client credentials"}
```

I guess I am not defining the `EGA_CLIENT_ID` variable correctly? I am using Snakemake 5.16 and Python 3.7.2. Thanks a lot in advance for your advice.

Code:

```
import snakemake.remote.EGA as EGA

ega = EGA.RemoteProvider()
os.environ["EGA_USERNAME"] = "XXX"
os.environ["EGA_PASSWORD"] = "XXX"
os.environ["EGA_CLIENT_SECRET"] = "XXX"
os.environ["EGA_CLIENT_ID"] = "pyega3"
rule a:
  input:
      ega.remote("ega/EGAD00001002142/COLO_829_EPleasance_TGENPipe.bam.bai")
  output:
      "data/COLO_829BL_BCGSC_IlluminaPipe.bam.bai"
  shell:
      "cp {input} {output}"
```

Comment: "Bad client credentials" looks more like your username/password combination was not recognized. Do they match your EGA account?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - yes the match my account, I took them straight from the `CREDENTIALS_FILE` which I can successfully log in with when invoking `pyega3` from the command line.

Comment: Ok, that's good. Have you tried setting the environment variables before the line `ega = EGA.RemoteProvider`? Maybe the values are already used at this point?

Comment: Unfortunately changing the order results in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved it. The reason was the `EGA_CLIENT_ID` variable. In the `pyega3.py` [script](https://github.com/EGA-archive/ega-download-client/blob/master/pyega3/pyega3.py), there is a definition for the `client_id` for pyega3 v3.0.44 ("f20cd2d3-682a-4568-a53e-4262ef54c8f4"). After setting the `EGA_CLIENT_ID` to this value login was successful.

```
os.environ["EGA_CLIENT_ID"] = "f20cd2d3-682a-4568-a53e-4262ef54c8f4"
```

I think this is a bug and I filed it on Snakemake's git repository - the official documentation just requires definition of the `EGA_USERNAME` and `EGA_PASSWORD` variables, and while definition of `EGA_CLIENT_SECRET` will probably need to be done by the user, the client ID should be pulled automatically from the pyega3 version installed locally.

Of note, after successful login, the example download from the documentation failed with the following:

```
Missing input files for rule a:
ega/EGAD00001002142/COLO_829_EPleasance_TGENPipe.bam.bai
```

However, downloading files that I have access to worked, indicating that the paths to the files from the documentation are wrong or are access-protected.